# Возможность скачать таблицу в excel

Tags: php, html, excel

Нужно сделать возможность скачать таблицы: http://meowwiif.beget.tech/countreg.php

в формате excel, как это реализовать?
Благодарен за любую помощь

Comment: Посмотрите любую библиотеку для работы с excel через php, уверен, что трудностей не возникнет.

Comment: @Alexxosipov а можно линку где это описано?

Comment: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel вот, к примеру. "PHPExcel is a library written in pure PHP and providing a set of classes that allow you to write to and read from different spreadsheet file formats, like Excel (BIFF) .xls, Excel 2007 (OfficeOpenXML) .xlsx, CSV, Libre/OpenOffice Calc .ods, Gnumeric, PDF, HTML"

Comment: тут кажется проще вообще csv выдать да и все

Comment: @teran мне важно как можно проще :D

Comment: Здесь мы к сожалению не знаем ваши метрики «проще» или «сложнее», поэтому воспользуйтесь советом погуглить и выбрать самому наиболее подходящее решение.